# Manage button methods from separate view controllers in one class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have three separate view controllers that all are navigated to by using buttons. Currently I have only used the main ViewController class that was auto created when creating a new project. I have a few other buttons in the initial view that do things like print screen to the page and such. I would like to create other buttons on the other two separate view controllers. I'm having some issues trying to drag connections from the buttons within the other views to the one ViewController.m file I have. Is there a way to manage all of the buttons in separate views in the same ViewController.m file or do I need to create a new class for these other views? If so could someone point me in the right direction on how to link them to ViewContorller.m?

Comment: Your wording changes. Are your buttons in other views or other view controllers?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Objective-C. All of the objects I've been calling Views say View Controllers under them in the graphical UI tool.

Comment: Usually you want to have a `UIViewController` subclass for each View Controller in your storyboard. Each of these would then handle the buttons.

Comment: Okay. How can I "pair" a UIViewController subclass to a View Controller I have already created within the interface gui tool in xcode?

Comment: On the right side bar you should see a tab that looks like a document. In that tab there is something that says class. Once you click on the correct view controller, it probably has the default `UIViewController` value. You can change that to your subclass name.

Comment: Okay works like a charm. One last question and I think I'll be all set. Will I need to instantiate this new subclass within my main ViewController class or with it's subclass be called when navigating to the new page to interact with the buttons?

Comment: When the storyboard loads it should instantiate all the view controllers automatically.

Comment: @cabellicar123, the storyboard does not instantiate all the view controllers when it loads. It instantiates the initial one, and any controllers that are root view controllers of that first one (like the root view controller of a navigation controller, or the view controllers of a tab bar controller). Controllers that you segue to with pushes or modals are not instantiated until the segue is executed.

Comment: @rdelmar Interesting to know (I had a feeling I might have been over simplifying, but I use xibs). I don't think that should affect anything else discussed however. Thanks for the note though!